# How to subscribe to comp.lang.c using Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, usenet

How can I subscribe to `comp.lang.c` using Mozilla Thunderbird?

I do not understand such newsgroups much (I have no idea why they do not have a unique server address).

What should the correct Server Settings look like?

[image]

Comment: (fideli already answered this, but I edited a bit to make it more clear)

Comment: Lazer, do you still have doubts? If so: what's not clear about @fideli's answer?

Answer (score 8):

You would need to connect to an [NNTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) before you can subscribe to the `comp.lang.c` newsgroup. They used to come with service from your ISP but that is quite rare these days, but could be simple as `news.yourprovidername.com`. Or perhaps there's a free NNTP server out there?

Next, once you have a NNTP server name, enter *that* name for Server Name (where the screenshot now erroneously shows the *group* name `comp.lang.c`).

Finally, Thunderbird will show you a list of all groups, where you can select the group(s) you want.

Otherwise you could use [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c) in your browser.

Comment: I could suggest [Eternal September](http://www.eternal-september.org/) and [Aioe.org](http://aioe.org/). _(Note that since Aioe.org does not require registration, posts from it are likely to be blocked by other Usenet servers.)_

Answer (score 2):

Get a news server. Try http://www.elfqrin.com/hacklab/pages/nntpserv.php for some free ones. Add one as your nntp server.